# perl syntax for matching strings from a file

Tags: regex, string, perl, matching

I have been struggling with perl syntax. I am trying to learn enough to do a large conditional replacement on the source code of another project but keep running into trouble. I wrote a simple script to test my problems and this and it worked fine. I tried it on a file and it no longer worked. The file contains the same text as my test string.

I imagine I have to do something special reading in the file but I do not have a clue as to what.

test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $matching = 'Logger\.getInstance\(\)\.addEntry\(((.|\n)*),((.|\n)*),((.|\n)*),((.|\n)*)\)';
my $replacement = '"Logger\.getInstance\(\).addEntry\($1,$7\)"';

my $test_str = "Logger\.getInstance\(\)\.addEntry\(\"error\", \"Thing2D\.PATH_TYPE\", new Object\(\) \{\}\.getClass\(\)\.getEnclosingMethod\(\)\.getName\(\), \"New PATH_TYPE was added and not filled in\.\");";


print "----\nstring:\n" . $test_str . "\n\nreplaced:\n\n";

$test_str =~ s/$matching/$replacement/ee;
print "\n\n" . $test_str . "\n\n\n";


die qq[Usage: perl $0 <subject_file>\n] unless @ARGV == 1;

open my $fh_subject, qq[<], shift @ARGV or die qq[Cannot open input file: $!\n];

my $subject_content;
{
    local $/ = undef;
        $subject_content = <$fh_subject>;
}

print "----\nString:\n" . $subject_content . "\n\nreplaced:\n\n";

$subject_content =~ "s/$matching/$replacement/ee";
print $subject_content;
```

test.txt:

```
Logger.getInstance().addEntry("error", "Thing2D.PATH_TYPE", new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName(), "New PATH_TYPE was added and not filled in.");
```

and the command line:

```
./test.sh test.txt
```

Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$subject_content =~ s/$matching/$replacement/ee;
```

instead of

```
$subject_content =~ "s/$matching/$replacement/ee";
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple! Thank you very much. I'm trying to learn a bit of pearl for those repetitive tasks I do. This helps a lot!